# HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13 aw2xxx ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop no input/output sound devices

Tags: sound, keyboard, hp

I have a HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible-13-aw2xxx laptop, and i install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop as second option (first boot Windows 11).

The problem is that:

The only available output device in Sound Settings is `Dummy Output`.

The alsamixer is here:

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer

I can provide any other setting (pulseaudio,...) if you requested.

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas

[image]

[image]

Output of `aplay -l` command:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Edit 29/11/2021:**

Hello,

With a new installation of Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 LTS, what packages are needed to use [alsa hda analyzer](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer) (broken get url so use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pObFP.png)?

I have an HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13 aw2xxx and can hear only from the headphones when they are connected.

So, i may change some pins according to:

> Thanks for your help Huffer, I ended up finding the issue myself.
> This turned out to be a problem with the pin mapping (a couple of
> speaker pins were set to use the headphones' output rather than the
> Speaker output).
>
> If anyone else has this issue, I used ALSA's HDA-Analysier tool to
> debug this and make the required pinmap changes. I corrected the
> problem by changing the following pins:
>
> 0x17 to Audio Output 0x11 0x1d to Audio Output 0x11

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmhVf.jpg)

Can i do something similar from Windows 11 boot?

Comment: Please one problem in one question. There is no way to fix all in one answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok delete the second and the third problem.

Comment: HDMI output is selected. You can switch it by F6.

Comment: @Pilot6 I fresh reinstall the os. Alsamixer settings updated. Didn't help. Check the new print screen.

Comment: What happens if you press F6? And also there may be a key combination like Fn+Fx to switch HDMI and Analog.

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: Look at the laptop manual for a switch.

Comment: Ok, look at the last screenshot.

Comment: I see. It seems that analog is not detected.

Comment: As i can see the laptop doesn't have a hdmi port. Only two usb-type-c and one regural usb, a card reader slot, and a button to lock/unlock the camera.

Comment: Trying to fetch the manual: We're sorry

HP Customer Support site is temporarily unavailable.

We apologize for any inconvenience. Please check back later.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-spectre-13-ap0000-x360-convertible-pc/23238155/manuals

Comment: Check if upgrading to the latest kernel helps. `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` (and reboot).

Comment: After the reboot the dummy output device is gone, and now i have two devices (Multichannel Output sof-soundwire and Headphones -sof-soundwire) but still no sound.

Comment: May i try to install all necessary packages i want for a python project i made or it's possible to try another os (example FREEBSD)?

Comment: With ubuntu version 21.10 i can hear sound but only from headphones, not from laptop sound device.

Comment: There is a difference with this pc. From Windows 11, when i switch the headphones i must choose from which device i want to hear.

Comment: @Pilot6 Please review the question.